# Htmlunit refreshing a page event

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm having a problem with this site: https://sistemas.tjes.jus.br/siep_consulta/faces/jsp/pesquisar_tramitacao_guias_por_pessoa_pub.jsp

I enter in site and i search by "Nome da Parte"(name of people)
: PAULO DA SILVA SANTOS

I click in "Pesquisar"(Search), but inside Htmlunit i have to download the archives.
I click in radio button and after i click in "gerar relatório do processo"(Generate process report).

When I do this only works when I refresh the page, but when I go to the next page and refresh the page it returns to the first page.

How do I solve this?

My code: `do {

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            ((HtmlRadioButtonInput) page.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"formulario:masterDetail1\"]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/input").get(i)).setChecked(true);
            Page arch = ((HtmlAnchor) page.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"formulario:masterDetail1\"]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[2]")).click();

            IOUtils.copy(arch.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream(),
                    new FileOutputStream("D:\\testepdfs\\arq" + j + ".pdf"));        
            page = (HtmlPage) page.refresh();
            j++;
        }

        page = ((HtmlAnchor) page.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"formulario:masterDetail1-nb\"]/tbody/tr/td[7]/a")).click();
        System.err.println(page.asText());

    } while (hasNextPage(page));
```

`

Thank's! And sorry for my english.

Comment: I was wondering about the variable `j` and the use of `j++` here.

Comment: Is for archives Ex: arq1.pdf, arq2.pdf, etc